# Why do I get an offset error for the code below?

Tags: php

```
<?php
    $i = 0;

    $array = array('name', 'email', 'address');
    while ($array[$i]) {
        echo "$array[$i]<br>";

        $i++;
    }
?>
```

PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 3 in /workspace/Main.php on line 6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: Works perfectly for me...

Comment: var_dump($array[$i]) in while should point you the problem.

Comment: Btw it is a notice and not an error. To fix it you need to check if the value is set while(isset($array[$i]))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In while loop until your array has value. use `isset()` for it. change your while condition as below:

```
<?php
    $i = 0;

    $array = array('name', 'email', 'address');
    while (isset($array[$i])) {
        echo "$array[$i]<br>";

        $i++;
    }
?>
```